# SSAO sample kernels causes performance drop when camera is close to model?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have a problem in which when the camera gets closer to the model the performance drops.

I figured out that it was todo with the ssao sample kernels, but I cant seem to figure out why these are causing performance issues when close to a mesh.

When I comment out the samples for loop in the ssao render code that is when the performance goes back to how it should be, so this for loop is obviously some how causing the issue. I orginally thought it might be a shader problem but I cant find any problems in there either.

Any ideas? Here is all the code that you need...

***SSAO Setup Code***

```
// Create two frame buffers, one for ssao colour and another for ssao blur
_fbos.push_back(new Fbo(width, height, { new FboAttachment(width, height, GL_RED, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0) }, false));
_fbos.push_back(new Fbo(width, height, { new FboAttachment(width, height, GL_RED, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0) }, false));
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

std::uniform_real_distribution<GLfloat> rand_floats(0.0f, 1.0f);    // Generate random floats between 0.0 and 1.0
std::default_random_engine rand_generator;  // A generator for randomising floats

// Create temp iterator var
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)   // Iterate through each sample...
{
    glm::vec3 sample(rand_floats(rand_generator) * 2.0f - 1.0f, rand_floats(rand_generator) * 2.0f - 1.0f, rand_floats(rand_generator)); // the third parameter was wrong on this line

    sample = glm::normalize(sample);    // Normalise the sample
    sample *= rand_floats(rand_generator);  // Seed the randomisation

    float scale = static_cast<float>(i) / 64.0f;    // Get pixel position in NDC about the resolution size

    scale = Math::lerpf(0.1f, 1.0f, scale * scale);     // Interpolate the scale
    sample *= scale;    // Scale the s and t values

    _ssao_kernals.push_back(sample);    // Assign sample to the kernal array

    _u_samples.push_back(glGetUniformLocation(shader_programs[0], ("samples[" + std::to_string(i) + "]").c_str()));     // Get each sample uniform location
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; i++)       // For each sample / 4...
{
    glm::vec3 noise(rand_floats(rand_generator) * 2.0f - 1.0f, rand_floats(rand_generator) * 2.0f - 1.0f, 0.0f);    // Randomly generate a noise pixel
    _ssao_noise.push_back(noise);   // Assign noise pixel to noise array
}

/*
* Create a noise texture to remove any banding from the ssao
*/
glGenTextures(1, &_noise_texture); // generate the texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _noise_texture); // bind data
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, 4, 4, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &_ssao_noise[0]); // set texture data
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); // texture filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); // texture filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); // texture filtering 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT); // texture filtering
```

***SSAO Render Function***

```
_fbos[0]->Bind(); // bind ssao texture

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clear colour data on the screen

        glUseProgram(_shader_programs[0]); // Use the first shader pass

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SSAO_SAMPLE_RESOLUTION; ++i)   // For each ssao sample...
            glUniform3fv(_u_samples[i], 1, glm::value_ptr(_ssao_kernals[i]));   // Assign kernal uniform data

        glUniformMatrix4fv(_u_projection, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(Content::_map->GetCamera()->GetProjectionMatrix()));  // Assign camera projection uniform data

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);   // Set active texture to index 0
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _g_buffer_data->GetAttachments()[0]->_texture);    // Bind positions
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);   // Set active texture to index 1
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _g_buffer_data->GetAttachments()[1]->_texture);    // Bind normals
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);   // Set active texture to index 2
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _noise_texture);   // Bind the noise texture

        _screen_rect->Render(1);        // Render to screen rectangle

        // Blur ssao texture
        _fbos[1]->Bind();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(_shader_programs[1]);  // Use the second shader pass

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);   // Bind active texture to index 0
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fbos[0]->GetAttachments()[0]->_texture);  // Bind the final colour

        _screen_rect->Render(1);        // Render to screen rectangle
```

***SSAO Fragment Shader***

```
#version 330 core

out float FragColor;

in vec2 _texcoord;

uniform sampler2D gPosition;
uniform sampler2D gNormal;
uniform sampler2D texNoise;

uniform vec3 samples[64];

int kernelSize = 64;
float radius = 0.3;
float bias = 0.025;

const vec2 noiseScale = vec2(1920.0 / 4.0, 1080.0 / 4.0); 

uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
    vec3 fragPos = texture(gPosition, _texcoord).xyz;
    vec3 normal = normalize(texture(gNormal, _texcoord).rgb);
    vec3 randomVec = normalize(texture(texNoise, _texcoord * noiseScale).xyz);

    vec3 tangent = normalize(randomVec - normal * dot(randomVec, normal));
    vec3 bitangent = cross(normal, tangent);
    mat3 TBN = mat3(tangent, bitangent, normal);

    float occlusion = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < kernelSize; ++i)
    {
        // get sample position
        vec3 sample = TBN * samples[i]; // from tangent to view-space
        sample = fragPos + sample * radius; 

        // project sample position (to sample texture) (to get position on screen/texture)
        vec4 offset = vec4(sample, 1.0);
        offset = proj * offset; // from view to clip-space
        offset.xyz /= offset.w; // perspective divide
        offset.xyz = offset.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5; // transform to range 0.0 - 1.0

        // get sample depth
        float sampleDepth = texture(gPosition, offset.xy).z; // get depth value of kernel sample

        // range check & accumulate
        float rangeCheck = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, radius / abs(fragPos.z - sampleDepth));
        occlusion += (sampleDepth >= sample.z + bias ? 1.0 : 0.0) * rangeCheck;           
    }

    occlusion = 1.0 - (occlusion / kernelSize);  
    FragColor = pow(occlusion, 3.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected performance characteristic of SSAO.

The closer the texel you're calculating the AO for is to the camera the farther away the sample points around it will be in screen-space, and the less likely it is that those neighboring texels will be in the GPU's texture cache - which causes a massive performance hit.